# Why does adding braces to the inner most for loop give such weird results?

Tags: c#

This is a slightly modified answer I got to a previous question I asked here. I'm changing it to understand it better, when something weird happened.

For loops in C# are supposed to work this way:

```
for (initial increment value, end increment value, increment rate)
{
    // for loop body
}
```

The answer code I got seems to work but doesn't have braces around the inner most for loop. Here's the code:

```
using System;

class Prime_Screening
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prime numbers x, where: 0 < x < 100");
        bool prime;

        for (int num = 2; num <= 100; num++)
        {
            prime = true; /


            for (int div = 2; div <= Math.Sqrt(num); div++)
            // Why isn't the contents of this for loop in braces? Attempting it produces a weird output
                if(num % div == 0) 
                    prime = false;
                if (prime) 
                    Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
        }
    } 
}
```

I added braces to that for loop so that I could keep the code clear, but I got some oddly repeating output:

5, 7, 9. 11, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 21, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 27, 29, 29, 29, 29, 31... 93, 95, 95, 95, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 99,

Why? While we're on the subject, should if statements be in braces too?

Edit: Spelling/Grammar

Comment: execute automatic formatting for your code. this will correct the indentation and the reasons will become clear immediately.

Comment: In Visual Studio, type Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D somewhere in that file.

Comment: I was doing this in Notepad++ so this might be why the formatting wasn't clearer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the braces, but then only the first statement belongs to the loop.

Since here is not an `if-else` but two `if`s only the first belongs to the loop:

```
for (int div = 2; div <= Math.Sqrt(num); div++)
    if (num % div == 0)
        prime = false;
    if (prime)
        Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
```

that is the same as:

```
for (int div = 2; div <= Math.Sqrt(num); div++)
{
    if (num % div == 0)
        prime = false;
}
if (prime)
    Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
```

as opposed to this code where both belong to the loop:

```
for (int div = 2; div <= Math.Sqrt(num); div++)
{
    if (num % div == 0)
        prime = false;
    if (prime)
        Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
}
```

From msdn:  [for-loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

> The body of the loop consists of a statement, an empty statement, or a
>   block of statements, which you create by enclosing zero or more
>   statements in braces.

Comment: Thanks, this problem had thrown me for a loop! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get weird results is because an unbraced statement **only applies to the next statement**.

This is what gets compiled with no brace:

```
for (int div = 2; div <= Math.Sqrt(num); div++)
{
    // Why isn't the contents of this for loop in braces? Attempting it produces a weird output
    if(num % div == 0) 
        prime = false;
}

if (prime) 
     Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
```

Comment: *statement*, not *line*, to be pedantic.  This is relevant here because the following statement spans several lines.

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop does not need to be followed by a statement block (some number of statements wrapped in curly braces), it simply needs to be followed by a single statement.  A statement block is simply a way of transforming some number of statements into a single (complex) statement.

The statement that follows your inner `for` loop is:

```
if(num % div == 0) 
    prime = false;
```

If you wrapped that in braces it wouldn't change the code.  If you wrapped that and the following statement (the second `if` block) in braces (as your indentation appears to indicate) then you'll have changed the semantics of the code.

This same behavior applies to `if`, `while`, `foreach`, `do`, etc. structures as well, although [interestingly enough not try/catch/finally blocks](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/04/why-are-braces-required/)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the same applies to other structures as well and the `try-catch`-exception. Interesting link, learned the dangling else problem ;)

Comment: Agreed. C# is inconsistent here, I hope I remember this.

Answer (score 0):

We use braces when we have multiple statements to put in a code block. It can be for `for loop` `while loop` `if else` etc.

But we do not use braces when we have only one statement. The very next statement is considered in loop when we are not using braces.

In your situation you have to put both `if` conditions in the braces otherwise it will consider only first `if` condition inside the loop.

Comment: The second `if` *shouldn't* be inside of the `for` loop.  He put it in there and that is what broke his code.

Comment: I did put braces around both if statements, not just the first one. This is what led to the given results.

Comment: @Code_Steel you have to put only first statement inside the braces of inner loop to get correct results